# Packaging WAR in another WAR (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, war

I currently trying to migrate an application to Maven. Since the previously, the application was mix of web projects (with JSPs and JSs) and other "normal" projects. I am having a hard time packing all those modules into one. For the web projects, I chose the packaging as WAR and others I chose JAR. Now I am trying to make a master WAR file, that I can eventually deploy to Tomcat. But from I read, packaging a WAR in another WAR is not possible. And also I read that making the packaging as a JAR is doable. I just wanted to know is the first option totally out of the question? If JAR and a WAR is the only option, where do I put all the web stuff (JSP, JS, images etc.). Currently the WAR+JAR combo creates a final WAR file that is only 3KB big, which hardly looks realistic. I know I am missing something, but not sure where to look. The application is about 14 years old, so doesn't really conform to any framework that I can think of. EAR is not an option either, as the application has to be deployed on Tomcat. I wish TomEE was an option! :(

Comment: you can't package a war file into a war file but it is possible to overlay a war file using the maven war plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html - that might work for you

Comment: What's a "master war file"? The whole thing should be a single war file, and your projects that are JARs should be a dependency of that war project.

Comment: @DaveNewton My point was that the 40 odd projects that I have about 20 are packaged as WAR and rest as JAR, So want to package all of them in one WAR file. That is what I meant as the "master WAR" that I can deploy to Tomcat.

Comment: Are they web apps? Or non-web-apps? If non-web-apps, package them properly. If web apps, that's not really how WAR files work--but you can always pull them apart in arbitrary ways and repackage it. Is this an app that is being continuously updated, including its dependencies? How does it handle its dependency management now? What's the motivation for moving it to Maven?

Comment: I was able to get somewhere with the overlay thing. I will run with it a little further and see where it goes. But at the moment stuck on something else. So I will have to figure that out first. If the overlay doesn't work, i will come back. The motivation is that the application will be merged with another one.

Answer (score 0):

All your "JSP, JS, images etc" should go in a WAR file.I have an application packed in a WAR file that is running with all this in a hosted Tomcat. You can package the entire application as Java EE except there are Desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Just take your 20 wars and deploy them on the Tomcat. There is no need to bundle them into another artifact.